# how to pass onDrop callback to ImageInput

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, react-dropzone

I am trying to pass a callback so I can use ImageInput to save the files/images before the form is submitted..I am curious how this can be done.. onDrop, onChange etc.. don't do anything. Thanks!

```
const callback = () => { console.log("callback"); }
[..]
<ImageInput source="pictures" accept="image/*" onDrop={callback}>
  <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
</ImageInput>
```

Comment: You'll have to implement your own custom input for that. Those props are already used internally. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377179/admin-on-rest-send-extra-params-to-rest-call

Comment: Thanks @Gildas any reason why there wasn't a similar to onDrop prop exposed on ImageInput so someone can pass a callbacck? OnDelete would be nice too

Comment: Because we wanted to keep it the simplest possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include the onDrop event inside options properties.

```
const callback = () => { console.log("callback"); }
[..]
<ImageInput source="pictures" accept="image/*" options={{onDrop:callback}}>
  <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
</ImageInput>
```

Comment: is that for react-admin though?

Comment: I found this options feature in a github issue, it was asked on FieInput Component. ImageInput Extended on FIleInput, As it is works for me. see this issue for more details. https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2083